# i am able to build my django web app on heroku but while launching its showing these error(error log shown below)

Tags: python, django, web, heroku, deployment

```
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466995+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466995+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466996+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466997+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466998+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466999+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.466999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467000+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467006+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'
2020-05-20T05:56:19.467089+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.475859+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480935+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480936+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480937+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480937+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480937+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480938+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480938+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480939+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480939+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480940+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480940+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480941+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480941+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480941+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480942+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480942+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480943+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:19.480950+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'
2020-05-20T05:56:19.481078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-05-20T05:56:19.596780+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-20T05:56:19.596929+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-20T05:56:30.268327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-20T05:56:30.136932+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-05-20T05:56:30.137666+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:42344 (4)
2020-05-20T05:56:30.137832+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-05-20T05:56:30.142162+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147069+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147071+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147089+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147090+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147091+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147091+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147092+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147092+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147092+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147093+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147093+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147093+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147094+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147095+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147095+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147096+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147096+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147097+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147097+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147097+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147098+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147098+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147098+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147098+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'
2020-05-20T05:56:30.147170+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-20T05:56:30.174785+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-20T05:56:30.174894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 05:56:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-20T05:57:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pratik2018id@gmail.com
2020-05-20T05:58:33.312195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-20T05:58:33.137138+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 55249fc3 by user pratik2018id@gmail.com
2020-05-20T05:58:33.137138+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user pratik2018id@gmail.com
2020-05-20T05:58:41.864624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-20T05:58:41.792615+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-20T05:58:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-20T05:58:54.555292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pratiktiwari.herokuapp.com request_id=919fc5ce-1a7c-4eac-b422-234eac5d71db fwd="157.47.7.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-20T05:58:54.812869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pratiktiwari.herokuapp.com request_id=da5ebbad-9a34-45f6-ad03-25e3dc0fc619 fwd="157.47.7.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-20T05:58:55.457902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pratiktiwari.herokuapp.com request_id=99c01efe-5e96-44f9-8f18-ca5f4d94eea7 fwd="157.47.7.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-20T05:58:56.766927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pratiktiwari.herokuapp.com request_i
```

Comment: Share proc file command and your project structure

Answer (score 0):

your settings->INSTALLED_APPS has a module which is not found by Django when trying to initialize:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'

Fix this issue and it will work